# Custom Authentication(Bearer) Token API Laravel

Tags: laravel, api, authentication

I have made an Laravel API with basic auth, made my own middleware setting the username like login default..

But I'm trying to custom the Authentication code, the Bearer;

I have this:
**Authentication: Basic cEVMb3RBUzpQM0wwVDRTMjAxOA==**

But i have to hash the username:passwordYYYY-mm-dd

What file and how can i change this?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Piter, welcome to SO. It seems like you could add some examples of your to this question to improve its quality and make it easier for people to help you.